# xbox burner to backup my xbox360 games isnt recognizing game in dvd drive right?ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-recommendation, burning, xbox-360

I was trying to use xbox burner to backup make backup copies of my sons Xbox games in case he scratched one up.

When I put the game in all I see is an audio file and video file in the media folder.  Xbox burner isn't recognizing an ISO file to use from the game at all.  Also when I put the game in vlc opens it but has errors on the audio and video files but shows the Xbox splash screen.  Does anyone know how to make Xbox burner work correctly?  Or give me step by step instructions on what I need to set this up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

## It is discouraged, difficult, unnecessary, and illegal in some locations.

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_protection#Video_game_console_systems):

> The Xbox has a specific function: Non-booting or non-reading from CDs and DVD-Rs as a method of game copy protection. Also, the Xbox is said to use a different DVD file system (instead of UDF). It has been theorized that the discs have a second partition that is read from the outside in (opposite current standards thus making the second partition unreadable in PC DVD drives) which give the tracks the appearance that the disc was spun backwards during manufacture. The Xbox 360 copy protection functions by requesting the DVD drive compute the angular distance between specific data sectors on the disc. A duplicated DVD will return different values than a pressed original would.

This is meant to keep users from copying disks. It is, in a nutshell, made so that you can't use CD-R's and need disks that were manufactured to have special layouts of sectors upon the physical surface. This is done as such copies are not generally legal. Also, the fact that a proprietary filesystem is used means that discs cannot be read using normal drives and filesystem utilities.

> <sub>**Legal disclaimer**: This is not meant to be legal advice. The author of this answer and Stack Exchange, Inc will not be responsible for any damages, incidental, or consequential, that may arise due to the use of these guidelines. These guidelines are based on US laws and regulations. Laws and regulations in your area may differ so check with a lawyer or local authorities.</sub>

Comment: after researching google I had seen where it is illegal to copy an xbox game in order to distribute outside the household,this was not my intention.I actually bought the game I m trying to copy and only doing this to put the original up because my 8 yo seems to scratch the games up.After days of research I was under the impression that as long as my intentions were to backup an original which I had purchased and not sell copies I was legal.If it is,however,illegal all the way around that wasnt my intention.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, you need a special DVD drive to backup your games. I believe these drives are called 0800 drives and are something along the lines of an official Xbox360 DVD drive. You usually need Windows for the whole back-up process, but there are softwares that are compatible with Ubuntu Linux as well. [www.GameBackupSystem.com](http://www.GameBackupSystem.com) is one of them.

I would look into GameBackupSystem a bit more, looks like a decent product.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can have the xbox modded and it will play backups, copying games however (which is what you are doing when you load his games onto a computer) requires ripping programs you can get from xbox modding forums. Be wary though, if you don't know what you are doing you can brick his xbox, best thing is to hire someone to mod it for you. Also the law states one copy per owned media to protect against selling backups. It's not illegal to make one copy. Hope this helps.